# Why does the use of yyclearin not trigger %destructor in bison

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I get a memory leak in the error recovery of a bison grammar although there is a %destructor handler. It seems it depends on the use of yyclearin.

Here is an extract from the grammar:

```
%union {
    int val;
    const char* str; /* allocated in the lexer with strdup() */
}
%token <int> KEYWORD
%token <str> STR
%destructor { free($$); } <str>
...
%%
...
problem
    : KEYWORD KEYWORD STR {doSomething(); free($3); }
    | KEYWORD ERROR       { yyclearin; yyerrok; someResync(); }
    ;
```

For the following input:

```
KEYWORD KEYWORD "string1"
KEYWORD "string2"
```

The first input line matches the first rule and the string gets freed 'manually' by the belonging action.
The second input line gets picked by the error rule. The string read as a lookahead
token triggers the error and gets forgotten by the yyclearin. But the
allocated memory still leaks. What need to be done to get the %destructor called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an excellent question.

I would have thought that discarding the lookahead token would fall into the category of "when user actions cannot manage memory". But all `yyclearin` does is to reset `yych`, forcing a new token to be read the next time lookahead is needed.

Effectively, that means that your use action (which calls `yyclearin`) needs to manage memory. By breaking into bison's internals a bit, we can do that fairly simply:

```
#define my_yyclearin \
      yydestruct ("Clearin: discarding", yytoken, &yylval); \
      yychar = YYEMPTY;
```

(If you use locations, you'll have to add `yylloc` to the `yydestruct` call.)

`yydestruct` is an undocumented bison internal which invokes the correct destructor and prints out a teace message if tracing is enabled. `yytoken` is an internal version of the token value kept in `yychar` (using a compressed range of index values to reduce table size). The `yychar` and `yylval` variables are documented so they should be safe to use.

That's at best a crude workaround. I've reported this problem as a bug to the bison maintainers.

Comment: Thanks this works. I slightly changed the macro definition to support the semicolon in the usage by enclosing it in "do {...} while(1)".